# Android (bottom) style navbar with icons on MAUI blazor

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5, maui-blazor

I'm trying to make a navbar fixed to the bottom that simulates a Tab Bar, with icons on top of the page name.
Here's the code on my NavMenu.razor:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand fixed-bottom bg-dark justify-content-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-justified w-100 text-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link d-flex flex-column" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <i class="bi bi-house-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Home</span>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link d-flex flex-column" href="book">
                <i class="bi bi-calendar-check-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Book</span>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link d-flex flex-column" href="profile">
                <i class="bi bi-person-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Profile</span>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link d-flex flex-column" href="settings">
                <i class="bi bi-gear-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Settings</span>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my MainLayout.razor:

```
<div class="page">
<NavMenu />

<main>
    <article class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </article>
</main>
```

But the result is terrible:
[image: navbar screenshot]

Even though this jsfiddle shows the correct behaviour:
https://jsfiddle.net/5orphjv4/2/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just noticed the same happens on a blazor webapp, not only on maui blazor hybrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce you problem and this is because the navbar uses the default **NavMenu.razor.css**. You can fix it by change the default css style.

1. Make the first nav item at the same line as others:

Open the **NavMenu.razor.css** below the NavMenu.razor, and delete the below code:

```
.nav-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
```

2. Make the clicked effect contains the text:

Open the **NavMenu.razor.css** below the NavMenu.razor, and change the height of the nav item:

```
.nav-item ::deep a {
    color: #d7d7d7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 5rem;<!-- old value is 3rem -->
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: Yeah the morning shower gave me the same answer, I'm new to MAUI and html/css so I completely forgot about the nested file